# Characters to use for \r\n when inserting into SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, insert

I'm attempting to insert some data from MySQL to SQL Server. I've dumped the MySQL table to a text file as SQL insert statements. I can insert it into SQL Server ok but the carriage returns are inserting as \r\n rather than as control sequences. How can I replace the \r\n strings in the MySQL insert statements so that they will end up as carriage returns in SQL Server?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to replace `\r\n` with `' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '`.

Comment: +1, and you are spot on. 

replace( variable_or_fieldname, '\r\n', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) )

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the \r\n escape sequence with a line break. Example:

```
select 'This is
a multi-line
string'
```

Comment: in my case it was a \n only.