# Inserting \n in sql table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to insert in a table some pieces of code. For example:

table:

```
create table  [tbl_cfg](
    [tabid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    cust_code nvarchar(max) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]


Insert into tbl_cfg(cust_code)
select ' this is the first line
         this is the second line'
```

My problem is that when I do this, sql automatically flatterns my code i.e. any \n is replaced with spaces.

If I insert it with Edit top 200 rows and I just paste the code, only the first line is inserted.

UPDATE:

In order to test this:
    select * from tbl_cfg
copy the code and paste it in another window

Comment: What makes you say that SQL Server "flattens" the text?

Comment: I explained: any \n is replaced with spaces

Comment: This might be helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053793/characters-to-use-for-r-n-when-inserting-into-sql-server

Comment: Try Char(10) and Char(13) instead of \n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According my experience about this issue:

Your strings with  `\n` is still in the original format in sql table, but when you do select it is presented in a single line.

However, for example if you put the string to html code, you'll see `\n` is still there.

Comment: +1 : One should never assume that presentation format = storage format.  Always check the values programatically using their native type, not visually.

Answer (score 0):

check http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/22/sql-server-t-sql-script-to-insert-carriage-return-and-new-line-feed-in-code/

Answer (score 0):

That's because you aren't seeing the result in text mode.

See this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/120427/) and view the results with "Results to Text" checked and unchecked.