# SQL SELECT adds forward slashes and \r\n to result string

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve some data from SQL Server. One of the attributes of the entity inside the database is a varchar in this format

```
{"someKey": "someValue", "anotherKey": "anotherValue", ...}
```

However, when I try to query that information, it gets returned like this:

```
{\"someKey\": \"someValue\",\r\n \"anotherKey\":\"anotherValue\",\r\n ...}
```

How can I retrieve the data without the added slashes etc?

Comment: It may not be performant but [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2053806/418950) suggests you `replace( variable_or_fieldname, '\r\n', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) )`  I am reasonably sure I've resorted to this approach when the performance hit was negligible for my purposes.

Comment: when querying using replace(), it doesn't seem to recognize \r\n or \ as a part of the string

Comment: What are you trying to query it with? The data is already JSON format in the database, it seems like you're trying to JSON encode it a second time via NodeJS or something.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just your client app displaying it like that? Please show the code you are using to query

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I ended up using JSON_QUERY(attribute/expression) in the sql statement which would extract an object from a JSON string.

Comment: For others wondering what this is, added with SQL Server 2016, [JSON_QUERY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql)